# Node.js - child process: work with input/output

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, stream

I need working with input and output of Chrome child process, but my experiments failed.

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

let chrome = spawn(
    '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome',
    [
        '--new-window', '--window-size=1200,1000',
        '--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--repl',
        'https://www.google.com'
    ],
);
chrome.stdout.on('data', data => { console.log('stdout:', data.toString('utf8')); });
chrome.stderr.on('error', err => { console.warn('stderr:', err.toString('utf8')); });
chrome.on('error',        err => { console.error(err.toString('utf8')); });
chrome.on('exit',        code => { console.log('Exit code:', code); });

setTimeout(() => {
    chrome.stdin.cork();
    chrome.stdin.write('123' + '\n', 'utf8', err => err && console.error(err));
    chrome.stdin.uncork(); // TODO not work - not send data to stream

    // chrome.stdin.end(); // this work, but it closes stream
}, 1000);

// missed console.log('stdout:' ...
```

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

let chrome = spawn(
    '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome',
    [
        '--new-window', '--window-size=1200,1000',
        '--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--repl',
        'https://www.google.com'
    ], {
        stdio: ['pipe', process.stdout, process.stderr]
    }
);

// TODO not work - output is showed in terminal output, but event is not called
process.stdout.on('data', data => { console.log('stdout:', data.toString('utf8')); });
process.stderr.on('error', err => { console.warn('stderr:', err.toString('utf8')); });

chrome.on('error',        err => { console.error(err.toString('utf8')); });
chrome.on('exit',        code => { console.log('Exit code:', code); });

process.stdin.write('111' + '\n', 'utf8', err => err && console.error(err));

setTimeout(() => {
    process.stdin.write('222' + '\n', 'utf8', err => err && console.error(err));
}, 1000);

// missed console.log('stdout:' ...
```

I do not know work with stream, so I suppose I made a mistake somewhere in the code.

If possible, I do not want to install external libraries.

Thanks in advance for all the solutions.

Edit:

- stream example: chrome.stdin.end(); work, but it closes stream

Comment: The first example is functional, except stderr should be handling the `data` event.

Comment: Try that same code running `cat`.  but add `setTimeout(() => chrome.stdin.end(), 4000)` Chrome might be buffering input/output so you don't see it?